# Running Azure pipeline tasks inside a docker

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hi I'm looking to move our jenkins pipeline build to the Azure Pipeline to build our application.

In Jenkins we are using the groovy script and we are building our application inside of local docker image.

In groovy we are using this:
`withDockerContainer(args: '-v /home/jenkins:/home/jenkins ' , image: dockerImage )`

From the Jenkins documentation (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/docker-workflow/)

Does exist any way to do the same thing in Azure.  I would like to be able to specify to run a specific task inside of a specific local docker image

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops) for that:

```yaml
trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-18.04'

jobs:
- job: u18
  steps:
  - bash: |
      cat /etc/issue

- job: u20
  container: ubuntu:20.04

  steps:
  - bash: |
      cat /etc/issue
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: But this accordingly of the documentation, will fetch the docker image from the Docker Hub? Isn't it?

Comment: No, this is not limited just to Docker Hub, Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#endpoints)

Comment: It is always trying to pull the docker image: /usr/bin/docker pull u14.04/d6xx:V6
WARNING: Error loading config file: .dockercfg: $HOME is not defined
Error response from daemon: Get https://u14.04/v2/: unexpected EOF

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: trigger: none
pr: none

pool:
  name: MyVstsPool


jobs: 
- job: docker
  container: u14.04/d6xx:V6 # my docker image already available where my Microsoft Agent is running
  steps:
  - script: |
      cat /etc/issue

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

> Does exist any way to do the same thing in Azure. I would like to be able to specify to run a specific task inside of a specific local docker image

The answer is yes.

If you want to run a task in local docker image, you need create a private agent on the machine where your local docker image exists:

Then you could use following scripts to invoke the local docker image:

```
pool:
  name: YourPrivateAgent

resources:
  containers:
  - container: pycontainer
    image: YourImage

steps:
- task: AnotherTask@1
  target: pycontainer
```

You could check the document [Step target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#step-target) for some more details.

Comment: It is always trying to pull the docker image: /usr/bin/docker pull u14.04/d6xx:V6 WARNING: Error loading config file: .dockercfg: $HOME is not defined Error response from daemon: Get u14.04/v2: unexpected

Comment: trigger: none pr: none pool: name: MyVstsPool jobs: - job: docker container: u14.04/d6xx:V6 # my docker image already available where my Microsoft Agent is running steps: - script: | cat /etc/issue